# Netbeans 8.0 does not upload modified files

Tags: remote-server, netbeans-8

I recently installed netbeans 8.0 in my computer Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 LTS, and when I 'm trying to update remote server with project version, there are no files selected to upload. 
This is too hard for me because I'm not capable to remember all files modified on each revision, and I dont want to spent so much time uploading entire project. 
       Does anyone knos how to manage this issue? I've read about this as a bug, but I dont know how to fix it. I'm very confused!

Thanks in advance.